# can someone explain what are the '+' and '-' in the error output of pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

in the example below, can someone please explain what does the '-' and '+' are for?

```
import  pytest
assert  'foo 1 bar' == 'foo 2 bar'

E   –   foo   1   bar
E   ?         ^   bar
E   +   foo   2   bar
E   ?         ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-` sign indicates something that is on the left part on the assertion and not on the right one.

`+` sign indicates something that is on the right part on the assertion and not on the left one.

Comment: You're welcome. If you consider this answer the question, please mark as solved.

Comment: *on the left/right part on the assertion* — on the left/right part of the **comparison**, I'd say.